# Stopping a custom SQLCLR aggregate early

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions, sqlclr

Let's say I want I have a table with the following columns and values:

```
| BucketID   | Value       |
|:-----------|------------:|
| 1          |    3        |
| 1          |    2        |
| 1          |    1        |
| 2          |    0        |
| 2          |    1        |
| 2          |    5        |
```

Let's pretend I want to partition over BucketId and Multiply the values in the partition:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BucketId, MULT(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY BucketId)
```

Now, there is no built-in Aggregate MULT function so I am writing my own using SQL CLR:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

[Serializable]
[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.Native, Name = "MULT")]
public struct MULT
{
    private int runningSum;

    public void Init()
    {
        runningSum = 1;
    }

    public void Accumulate(SqlInt32 value)
    {
        runnningSum *= (int)value;
    }

    public void Merge(OverallStatus other)
    {
        runnningSum *= other.runningSum;
    }

    public SqlInt32 Terminate()
    {
        return new SqlInt32(runningSum);
    }
}
```

What my question boils down to is, let's assume I hit a 0 in `Accumulate` or `Merge`, there is no point continuing on. If that is the case, how can I return 0 as soon as I hit 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot force a termination since there is no way to control the workflow. SQL Server will call the `Terminate()` method as each group finishes processing its set.

However, since the state of the UDA is maintained across each row processed in a group, you can simply check `runningSum` to see if it's already `0` and if so, skip any computations. This would save some slight amount of time processing.

In the `Accumulate()` method, the first step will be to check if `runningSum` is `0`, and if true, simply `return;`. You should also check to see if `value` is `NULL` (something you are not currently checking for). After that, check the incoming `value` to see if it is `0` and if true, then set `runningSum` to `0` and `return;`.

```cs
public void Accumulate(SqlInt32 value)
{

  if (runningSum == 0 || value.IsNull)
  {
    return;
  }

  if (value.Value == 0)
  {
    runningSum = 0;
    return;
  }

  runningSum *= value.Value;
}
```

Note: Do not cast `value` to `int`. All `Sql*` types have a `Value` property that returns the expected native .NET type.

Finally, in the `Merge` method, check `runnningSum` to see if it is `0` and f true, simply `return;`. Then check `other.runningSum` to see if it is `0`, and if true, then set `runnningSum` to `0`.

Comment: It would require careful testing to see if there's any point to this. Specifically, inserting conditional statements will involve extra instructions and (possibly) branches that may well turn out to be slower than simply multiplying unconditionally (depending on what the JIT compiler makes of it).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Fair enough as far as this particular scenario, which is rather simple, is concerned. But for more complex scenarios, this technique is quite helpful :-).